# html id and class format

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a single page that just displays a div. When I try to use classes or IDs as selectors, my elements won't format, but when I use the actual element as a selector, it formats just fine.

Comment: Let us take a look at your HTML and CSS

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i give an example :

```
<div id="centerBox"> 
      <p>Some text for the center div</p> 
 </div>

<div class="centerText"> 
      <p>Some text for the center div</p> 
 </div>
```

html page centerBox is id (#) and centerText is class (.)
 example :

```css
#centerBox {
    background-color:green;
}
.centerText {
     background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="centerBox"><p>Some text for the center div</p>
</div>
<div class="centerText"><p>Some text for the center div</p>
</div>
```